# Server 2008 R2 PS script cannot update Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

I have a Powershell script that updates users attributes in Active Directory that runs just fine from the PowerShell ISE.  However when I try to run the script as a scheduled task it cannot access Active Directory to make the changes.

I know the script runs because it send an email when it starts and it sends an email in the catch block of code when it crashes.  It crashes at the attempt to update AD.

Account I am using is a Domain Administrator so I would not thinh it is a user permission issue.  Is there some reason this script is not able to access AD?

Thanks for your help

Perry

Comment: Who does the scheduled task run as?

Comment: The task runs as an account which is a member of the DomainAdmin security group

Comment: What is the command line (including parameters) you are using for the scheduled task?

Comment: Do you have "Run with highest privileges" checked?

Comment: The script is called from a batch file with this code `@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'" ` 
pause.  I do have the "Run with highest privileges" checked

Comment: @Perry so it's a scheduled task but is still called from a batch file? Try to do it without batch just a scheduled powershell task.

Comment: @SimonS I changed the task to just call the script without the batch file.  Get the same results as soon as it tries to access Active Director it crashes. ???

Answer (score 0):

Getting a PowerShell script to run as a scheduled task on Server 2008 R2 can be a tricky task. Here is what I did and it works.

## Scheduled Task Settings

### General

#### Security options:

- Run whether user is logged on or not (selected)
- Do not store password. The task will only have access to local resources (unchecked)
- Run with highest privileges (checked)
- Configure for: (Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2)

It appears your triggers are correct because the script is running.

### Actions

- Action: Start a program
- Program/script: *path to PowerShell* (e.g. C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe)
- Add arguments (optional): *.\file.ps1*
- Start in (optional): *path of directory where file.ps1 is found* (e.g. C:\folder\scripts)

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get the script to work.  The script was being run however it failed when it attempted to make a call to the Active Directory.  The solution was to add the Active Directory module to Powershell.  I found the instructions on how to do that [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/#windows-server-2008-r2).  I also added set-executionpolicy remotesigned and import-module activedirectory to the top of my scrpt to make sure these were set as well.  Once I made those changes the script worked just fine.

Thanks for all you comments and suggestion

Perry